# How to fill a PDF field in the client-side (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, pdf, client-side, fill

I need to create a application that needs to get information from the user using HTML text fields and fill-it to PDF fields. The fill-able PDF can be obtained from the server. The data filled in by the user cannot be submitted to the server (Sensitive information / legal problems). I need a way in which the JavaScript can take the information filled by the user, and fill it to the PDF, and make it available for the user to print/download.

(Initially, I tried to to just have HTML+PRINTCSS and avoid using a PDF, but then I had the issue of headers added by browsers to HTML that is printed. I don't want the worry the user to check his browser print settings - as most of them are computer illiterate)

Comment: How about the generation pdf file with POST or GET data handling?

Comment: No, That would require data to be sent to the server.

Comment: Why you don't want use the native pdf fields without any external scripting? The problem is you can not see incapsulated objects of PDF file from outside scripting environment. You can download file to client Hard Drive, decompose it and reassemble with new textual data. There is a WIERD way to hack the file by "injection" the text strings inside the binary, but client have to: (a) download the file and (b) use filesystem object in javascript for the file editing. I not sure clients will give you permission to work with HD directly from the script.

Comment: SWF files can read environment like html tag values. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this post helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944404/fill-pdf-form-with-javascript-client-side-only. Or this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965682/fill-pdf-form-created-in-scribus-from-client-side-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is doable via JavaScript alone. Some PDF readers do support JS, but many do not or allow the user to toggle it, and even then the PDF wouldn't have access to variables in the browser window. You'd be better off pre-filling the fields serverside. PHP in particular has robust [PDF handling](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php) available out of the box.

You could, for instance, let the user fill in the form online - the "Print" button could use AJAX to submit the form to the server, and point the window at the resulting PDF download link. You could also simply submit the form without JavaScript, and let the server handle the redirection by setting the header.