# Fill pdf form with javascript (client-side only)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

I need to fill a pdf form automatically in my angularjs webapp. The pdf form is generated outside the app so I can configure it as I want.

In my app, I just need to load the pdf, modify the form fields and flatten the file so it doesn't look like a form anymore.

Do you know any way to do it?

Edit:
I've found [iText](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=175) but it's a java library which won't work for my project (the app runs on tablets so I'm looking for something 100% HTML5)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've found a solution...not perfect but it should fit most requirements. It doesn't use any server (perfect for privacy requirements) or library! First of all, the PDF must be version 1.5 (Acrobat 6.0 or later). The original pdf can be another version but when you create the fields you must save it as compatible for Acrobat 6.0 or later. If you want to make sure the format is right, you can check [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986609/pdf-form-field-in-a-text-editor)

So let's say I have 'myform.pdf' file (with no form fields); I open it with Acrobat Pro (I have Acrobat Pro 11 but it should work with other versions). I add fields and pre-fill the field's value (not the field name!) with a 'code' (unique text string). This code will be find/replace with the string you want by the javascript function below so let say '%address%' (you can add multiple fields but use a different code to differenciate fields). If you want to have a flatten look of the field, set the field to read-only. To save it, go to File -> Save as other... -> Optimized PDF and choose "Acrobat 6.0 and later" under Make compatible with (top right of the pop-up).

Once you have your file saved, you can check that the format is right by opening it in a text editor and looking for your codes (in my case '%address%'). Count number of occurences, it should appear three times.

The following function does three things:
- Changes the fields content
- Recalculate the content's length
- Fix the cross reference tables

So now the function (look at the end for the final pdf blob):

@param certificate: your pdf form (format of this variable must be compatible with [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader))

@param changes: the field changes, [{find: '%address%', replace: '2386 5th Street, New York, USA'}, ...]

```
// Works only for PDF 1.5 (Acrobat 6.0 and later)
    var fillCertificate = function (certificate, changes) {


        // replace a a substring at a specific position
        String.prototype.replaceBetween = function(start, end, what) {
            return this.substring(0, start) + what + this.substring(end);
        };
        // format number with zeros at the beginning (n is the number and length is the total length)
        var addLeadingZeros = function (n, length) {
            var str = (n > 0 ? n : -n) + "";
            var zeros = "";
            for (var i = length - str.length; i > 0; i--)
                zeros += "0";
            zeros += str;
            return n >= 0 ? zeros : "-" + zeros;
        }


        // Create the reader first and read the file (call after the onload method)
        var reader = new FileReader();
        // To change the content of a field, three things must be done; - change the text of the field, - change the length of the content field, - change the cross table reference
        reader.onload = function(aEvent) {
            var string = aEvent.target.result;

            // Let's first change the content and the content's length
            var arrayDiff = [];
            var char;
            for(var foo = 0; foo < changes.length; foo++) {
                // Divide the string into a table of character for finding indices
                char = new Array(string.length);
                for (var int = 0; int < string.length; int++) {
                    char[int] = string.charAt(int);
                }
                // Let's find the content's field to change and change it everywhere
                var find = changes[foo].find;
                var replace = changes[foo].replace;
                var lengthDiff = replace.length - find.length;
                var search = new RegExp(find, "g");

                var match;
                var lastElements = [];
                var int = 0;
                var objectLenPos;
                var objectLenEnd;
                // Each time you change the content, compute the offset difference (number of characters). We'll add it later for the cross tables
                while (match = search.exec(string)) {
                    arrayDiff.push({index: match.index, diff: lengthDiff});
                    lastElements.push({index: match.index, diff: lengthDiff});
                    // Find length object
                    if(int == 0){
                        var length = 0;
                        var index;
                        while(char[match.index - length] != '\r'){
                            index = match.index - length;
                            length++;
                        }
                        objectLenPos = index + 10;
                        length = 0;
                        while(char[objectLenPos + length] != ' '){
                            length++;
                            objectLenEnd = objectLenPos + length;
                        }
                    }
                    int++;
                }
                var lengthObject = string.slice(objectLenPos, objectLenEnd) + ' 0 obj';

                var objectPositionStart = string.search(new RegExp('\\D' + lengthObject, 'g')) + lengthObject.toString().length + 2;
                var length = 0;
                var objectPositionEnd;
                while(char[objectPositionStart + length] != '\r'){
                    length++;
                    objectPositionEnd = objectPositionStart + length;
                }

                // Change the length of the content's field

                var lengthString = new RegExp('Length ', "g");
                var fieldLength;
                var newLength;

                string = string.replace(lengthString, function (match, int) {
                    // The length is between the two positions calculated above
                    if (int > objectPositionStart && int < objectPositionEnd) {
                        var length = 0;
                        var end;
                        while (char[int + 7 + length] != '/') {
                            length++;
                            end = int + 7 + length;
                        }
                        fieldLength = string.slice(end - length, end);
                        newLength = parseInt(fieldLength) + lengthDiff;

                        if (fieldLength.length != newLength.toString().length) {
                            arrayDiff.push({index: int, diff: (newLength.toString().length - fieldLength.length)});
                        }
                        // Let's modify the length so it's easy to find and replace what interests us; the length number itself
                        return "Length%";
                    }
                    return match;
                });

                // Replace the length with the new one based on the length difference
                string = string.replace('Length%' + fieldLength, 'Length ' + (newLength).toString());
                string = string.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
            }


            // FIND xref and repair cross tables
            // Rebuild the table of character
            var char = new Array(string.length);
            for (var int = 0; int < string.length; int++) {
                char[int] = string.charAt(int);
            };
            // Find XRefStm (cross reference streams)
            var regex = /XRefStm/g, result, indices = [];
            while ( (result = regex.exec(string)) ) {
                indices.push(result.index);
            }
            // Get the position of the stream
            var xrefstmPositions = [];
            for(var int = 0; int < indices.length; int++){
                var start;
                var length = 0;
                while(char[indices[int] - 2 - length] != ' '){
                    start = indices[int] - 2 - length;
                    length++;
                }
                var index = parseInt(string.slice(start, start + length));
                var tempIndex = parseInt(string.slice(start, start + length));
                // Add the offset (consequence of the content changes) to the index
                for(var num = 0; num < arrayDiff.length; num++){
                    if(index > arrayDiff[num].index){
                        index = index + arrayDiff[num].diff;
                    }
                }
                string = string.replaceBetween(start, start + length, index);
                // If there is a difference in the string length then update what needs to be updated
                if(tempIndex.toString().length != index.toString().length){
                    arrayDiff.push({index: start, diff: (index.toString().length - tempIndex.toString().length)});
                    char = new Array(string.length);
                    for (var int = 0; int < string.length; int++) {
                        char[int] = string.charAt(int);
                    };
                }

                xrefstmPositions.push(index);
            }
            // Do the same for non-stream
            var regex = /startxref/g, result, indices = [];
            while ( (result = regex.exec(string)) ) {
                indices.push(result.index);
            }
            for(var int = 0; int < indices.length; int++){
                var end;
                var length = 0;
                while(char[indices[int] + 11 + length] != '\r'){
                    length++;
                    end = indices[int] + 11 + length;
                }
                var index = parseInt(string.slice(end - length, end));
                var tempIndex = parseInt(string.slice(end - length, end));

                for(var num = 0; num < arrayDiff.length; num++){
                    if(index > arrayDiff[num].index){
                        index = index + arrayDiff[num].diff;
                    }
                }
                string = string.replaceBetween(end - length, end, index);

                if(tempIndex.toString().length != index.toString().length){
                    arrayDiff.push({index: end - length, diff: (index.toString().length - tempIndex.toString().length)});
                    char = new Array(string.length);
                    for (var int = 0; int < string.length; int++) {
                        char[int] = string.charAt(int);
                    };
                }

                xrefstmPositions.push(index);
            }
            xrefstmPositions.reverse();
            var firstObject, objectLength, end;
            var offset;
            // Updated the cross tables
            for(var int = 0; int < xrefstmPositions.length; int++) {
                var length = 0;
                var end;
                if(char[xrefstmPositions[int]] == 'x'){
                    offset = 6;
                } else{
                    offset = 0;
                }
                // Get first object index (read pdf documentation)
                while(char[xrefstmPositions[int] + offset + length] != ' '){
                    length++;
                    end = xrefstmPositions[int] + offset + length;
                }
                firstObject = string.slice(end - length, end);

                // Get length of objects (read pdf documentation)
                length = 0;
                while(char[xrefstmPositions[int] + offset + 1 + firstObject.length + length] != '\r'){
                    length++;
                    end = xrefstmPositions[int] + offset + 1 + firstObject.length + length;
                }
                objectLength = string.slice(end - length, end);

                // Replace the offset by adding the differences from the content's field
                for(var num = 0; num < objectLength; num++){
                    if(char[xrefstmPositions[int]] == 'x'){
                        offset = 9;
                    } else{
                        offset = 3;
                    }
                    // Check if it's an available object
                    if (char[xrefstmPositions[int] + 17 + offset + firstObject.length + objectLength.length + (num * 20)] == 'n') {
                        var objectCall = (parseInt(firstObject) + num).toString() + " 0 obj";
                        var regexp = new RegExp('\\D' + objectCall, "g");
                        var m;
                        var lastIndexOf;
                        // Get the last index in case an object is created more than once. (not very accurate and can be improved)
                        while (m = regexp.exec(string)) {
                            lastIndexOf = m.index;
                        }
                        string = string.replaceBetween(xrefstmPositions[int] + offset + firstObject.length + objectLength.length + (num * 20), xrefstmPositions[int] + 10 + offset + firstObject.length + objectLength.length + (num * 20), addLeadingZeros(lastIndexOf + 1, 10));
                    }
                    if(num == objectLength - 1){
                        if (char[xrefstmPositions[int] + offset + firstObject.length + objectLength.length + ((num + 1) * 20)] != 't'){
                            xrefstmPositions.push(xrefstmPositions[int] + offset + firstObject.length + objectLength.length + ((num + 1) * 20));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // create a blob from the string
            var byteNumbers = new Array(string.length);
            for (var int = 0; int < string.length; int++) {
                byteNumbers[int] = string.charCodeAt(int);
            }

            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

            var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type : 'application/pdf'});

// Do whatever you want with the blob here

        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(certificate);

    }
```

So the code is not clean at all but it works :)

Let me know if you have any question

Comment: I know this answer covers a lot, but an example implementation would be great.  I keep getting TypeError: Argument 1 of FileReader.readAsBinaryString does not implement interface Blob.

Comment: @JohnathanElmore https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader says readAsBinaryString() is not standard... you should either try to use chrome or maybe use readAsText() (but I've never tried)

Comment: Could you provide an example how to generate the 'certificate'?

Comment: @Moritur The certificate is not generated, it is a file that you create outside your application (generally with adobe pro). The certificate is the form with empty fields that you need to upload to your app. Make sure this form meets the proper standard (version 1.5 - read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986609/pdf-form-field-in-a-text-editor for more details)

Comment: Thanks, I meant an example how to get the contents of the certificate variable which you pass to the function. E.g. how to load the pdf file with js. However, I think I got it to work already.

Comment: Another question regarding your code: The xref part seems not to work for me. A lot of the char[xrefstmPositions[int] + offset + 1 + firstObject.length + length] are just undefined. Here is a test pdf I'm using: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cwfa4dzcoqkuje6/form4.pdf?dl=0 (Maybe useful for other people to test with as well)

Comment: @Moritur Sorry but it's already two years I wrote this code and I can't remember exactly... the easiest way to debug is to open your file in notepad++ and try to do what the code does to see where it fails. My approach was super basic, I've just created a form and modified it through adobe. I then compared both files (initial and modified ones) and tried to see where were the differences. Sorry I can't help you more with that

Comment: This is more of a hack than a solution for production (it's far to be bullet proof). It is what it is until we get a real javascript library for PDF (which means never...)

Comment: Nevermind, thanks so far for your help! I already extended your code to work for checkboxes as well (with the method you described) which worked pretty well. With your agreement I might even make a little library out of it based on your code.

Comment: @Moritur Awesome, you have my blessing to do whatever you want with this code, I really encourage you to make a library. Hopefully someone else will improve it for newer versions of PDF

Answer (score 22):

There is now another solution that worked for me.
It's this JS package: https://github.com/phihag/pdfform.js
Also available on NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfform.js

If you have troubles opening your PDF files, the best bet is to use the mozilla's PDF.js library which works with every PDF files I tried.
The only drawback as of today is that it's not working as expected with webpack. You have to import the JS files with a `script` tag.

Answer (score 7):

[pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) was the best choice for me. Look, after trying many random solutions I found this lib that's very very simple to implement and, off-topic, has a great TS support (nowadays it means a lot ).

Fill form official example: https://pdf-lib.js.org/#fill-form

Comment: tried - doesn't work with non-english characters\

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, there is no client-side application on tablets which would do that.

That means you will need server-side support, and iText is indeed one of the products out there. Another one is FDFMerge by Appligent, which does fill and can be set to flattening.

Comment: Not very happy with the answer but thank you! It is very strange to see pdf libraries to create a pdf from scratch (jspdf, pdfmake, etc...) but not even one to fill a form (which seems to be a much easier operation!)

Comment: Right but you just need to read the form fields not the whole document... in addition, pdf can integrate javascript code which could help to interact with external code (I'm not a pro but I just guess)

Comment: OK, I wrote a solution...please see my answer