# Fill pdf form created in scribus from client side javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a pdf form, into which I want to fill a password generated in javascript, so that the user can print it. The password is sensitive and may not be send to the server, so this has to happen in client side javascript. In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944404/fill-pdf-form-with-javascript-client-side-only) it is possible using adobe acrobat.

The Idea is, that one creates a pre-filled form with a unique value, and  than replaces that value using somple search and replace in javascript when generating the final pdf for displaying the user.

Since I do not own actobat, I thought I try it with [scribus](http://www.scribus.net/).

I generated a test form in scribus and gave it the prefilled value `%HELLO%`. But looking at the resuling pdf, I do not see that I can replace  the `%HELLO%` value by the password with simple text replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, while this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944404/fill-pdf-form-with-javascript-client-side-only) already gives the answer in the code it does not explain it.

The value of TextField has to be converted to a sequence of hex-encoded unicode characters (so each 4 digits) and it has to start with "fffe". Using this string, one can do the search and replace in the pdf document.

The code also updates the "xref" in the pdf, which one has to do when the length of the pdf changes (or some elements are positioned different in the file). Since I did not change the length of the value of the TextField, I did not have to do that.